# Field Theory. Prove that $f(x)$ has a zero $m$ in $\Bbb Z$ and that $m$ must divide $a_0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Here is the problem:

[image]

I believe you can use Gauss' Lemma whose proof says that if there are polynomials $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ in $\Bbb Q[x]$ with $\deg g(x) < \deg f(x)$ such that $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, then there are polynomials $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ in $\Bbb Z[x]$ such that $\deg G(x) = \deg g(x), \deg H(x) = \deg h(x)$ and $f(x) = G(x)H(x). I'm just not positive how to do that exactly.

Thanks!

Comment: If $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ is a root of $f$ then there is $q\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $f(x)=(x-r)q(x)$. Applying Guass's Lemma, from the dyslexic brother of Gauss, you get that $f(x)=(x-m)Q(x)$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $Q\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Therefore, $f$ has an integer root $m$.

Comment: @Max: Look at the proof of the rational root test (no need for Gauss's lemma).

Comment: Assume $\frac uv$ is a rational root. Look at $v^{n-1}f(u/v)$, namely its top summand vs. all other summands. Once you know the root is integer, look at the constant term vs. all other summands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a monic polynomial in $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, any root $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$ of $f$ is also in $\mathbb{Z}$. This is because (assuming $\gcd(p,q)=1$),

\begin{eqnarray}
  0 
  &=& f(\frac{p}{q}) \\
  &=& \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k(\frac{p}{q})^k \\
  &=& \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k\frac{p^k}{q^k} \\
  &=& \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_kp^kq^{n-k} \\
\end{eqnarray}

where in the last line we multiplied the equation ($=0$) by $q^n$. In the last line, only the summand $p^n$ does not have the factor $q$, thus we see that $q | p^n$. Since $\gcd(p,q)=1$, it must be that $q=1.$ That is, the root is an integer.

Let the root be $m \in \mathbb{Z}$,

$$0=m^n + a_{n-1}m^{n-1} + ... +a_1m+a_0$$

and since $m$ divides LHS and the first $n-1$ summands, $m$ must also divide $a_0$. $\square$